# Prove the following determinant identities without expanding the determinants

Tags: determinant

a)
$$\begin{vmatrix}
  \sin^2 x & \cos^2 x & \cos 2x \\
  \sin^2 y & \cos^2 y & \cos 2y \\
  \sin^2 z & \cos^2 z & \cos 2z \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0;$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
  \sin^2 x & \cos^2 x & \cos^2x-\sin^2x \\
  \sin^2 y & \cos^2 y & \cos^2y-\sin^2y \\
  \sin^2 z & \cos^2 z & \cos^2z-\sin^2z \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0;$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
  \cos^2 x & \cos^2 x & \cos^2x-\sin^2x \\
  \cos^2 y & \cos^2 y & \cos^2y-\sin^2y \\
  \cos^2 z & \cos^2 z & \cos^2z-\sin^2z \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0;$$

b)
$$\begin{vmatrix}
   1 & a & p+c \\
   1 & p & c+a \\
   1 & c & a+p \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0,$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & a & 1\cdot(a+p+c) \\
    1 & p & 1\cdot(p+c+a) \\
    1 & c & 1\cdot(c+a+p)
\end{vmatrix} =
(a + p + c)\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & a & 1 \\
    1 & p & 1 \\
    1 & c & 1
\end{vmatrix} = 0.$$

I am stuck on a), any hints and help is appreciate, and please check if b) is correct.

Comment: I've replaced the title with something more coherent -- One does not "prove" a determinant. (One could *compute* it, or prove that some claim about its value is correct.)

Comment: b) is correct.  You have made the two columns linearly dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already looked up and found this, however, I'm unsure what operation shall I go next for.

Comment: Futher you can add any column/row multiplied by any real number to any other column/row.

Comment: The third column is a linear combination of the first two.

Comment: I've edited the answer, could you check if I'm on the right track, if so what should I do next?

Comment: Now you have two equal columns, so matrix is degenerate and determinant is zero.